# Keep getting CANNOT POST /login everytime i login

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pug

I got the codes from a tutorial, seems to work fine until I made routers since I'm trying to create an E-commerce website with a login system.
This is my `index.js` code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const prodRouter = require('./server/routes/prodRouter');
const loginRouter = require('./server/routes/loginRouter');
const regRouter = require('./server/routes/regRouter');
const contRouter = require('./server/routes/contRouter'); 
const checkRouter = require('./server/routes/checkRouter'); 
const profRouter = require('./server/routes/profRouter'); 
const path = require('path'); const port = 3500; 
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'server/views')); 
app.set('viewengine', 'pug'); 
app.use('/prod', prodRouter); 
app.use('/login',loginRouter); 
app.use('/reg', regRouter); 
app.use('/cont',contRouter); 
app.use('/check', checkRouter); 
app.use('/profile',profRouter); 
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{res.render('Home.pug', {}); });     
app.listen(port, (err) => { // arrow function feature from ES6 if(err){ console.log(err); }
console.log(`Listening to port ${port}!`); });
```

and `loginRouter.js`

```
const express = require('express'); const router = express.Router();
const app = express(); 
const mysql = require('mysql'); 
const server = require('http').createServer(app); 
bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'login',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',   
}); 
users = []; connections = [];

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', {}); 
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true 
});

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
connection.connect();


app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var email= req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?',[email],function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
        // console.log("error ocurred",error);
            res.send({
                "code":400,
                "failed":"error ocurred"
            })
        }else{
            // console.log('The solution is: ', results);
            if(results.length >0){
                if([0].password == password){
                    return res.redirect('/profile');
                }else{
                    res.send({
                        "code":204,
                        "success":"Email and password does not match"
                    });
                }
            }else{
                res.send({
                    "code":204,
                    "success":"Email does not exits"
                });
            }
        }
    });
enter code here
});
module.exports = router;
```

my pug form:

```
form#login-form(method='post')
                  fieldset.input
                    p#login-form-username
                      label(for='modlgn_username') Email
                      input#modlgn_username.inputbox(type='text', name='email', size='18', required)
                    p#login-form-password
                      label(for='modlgn_passwd') Password
                      input#modlgn_passwd.inputbox(type='text', name='password', size='18', required)
                    .remember
                      p#login-form-remember
                        label(for='modlgn_remember')
                          a(href='#') Forget Your Password ?
                      input.button(type='submit', value='Sign In')
```

I'm pretty sure I did something wrong with the router, because every time I login, I keep getting `CANNOT POST` instead of going to the profile page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I added my pug code for form.

EDIT: the problem only occurs if the login page is not the main page.

example:

login page > *logs in > profile - no problem

home page > login page > *logs in > profile - error

Comment: after logging in, its suppose to go to localhost:3500/profile. Instead i keep getting localhost:3500/login where i get the CANNOT POST /login

Comment: on your browser - open dev tools (F12 in chrome) and go to network tab. When you try to login, see what route you get there and see if that matches to what you have in your router config.

Comment: i tried it but unfortunately i don't know what to look on the dev tool

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you don't have an action on your form (see [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) for details).  When you don't have an action the form is submitted to the URL it lives at, so if you POST on your home page without an action the post will go to /home.

Change the form element to look like this:

```
form#login-form(method='post' action='/login')
```

Comment: if i put action='/login' what happens is, it does not validate the email and password. Once i click the login button it just logs in anything even if the email and password are not in the database.

Comment: That is a separate problem then, your question was about how to solve the "cannot post" error which this does.  It's really up to you how you want to handle those errors on the server - redirect to an error page or leave them on the current page with an error message.  It would be a separate question on StackOverflow though if you need help with that.